# Simple Websocket in scala / akka / play

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, playframework-2.1

I would like to create a simple Websocket application using Scala / Akka / Play.

What I see from the examples (such as the [webchat](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat) or the [recent talk at the Scala Days](http://www.parleys.com/play/51c38b03e4b0ed877035686c/chapter0/about)), is a blend between JavaScript / Coffeescript, html templates and so on.

The clients of my Websocket application will be also native mobile apps (Android, iOS), so I need to think "out of the browser".

How can I create a websocket application that can simply push a "hello" string?

Comment: I'm confused. WebSockets are a workaround that exists because HTTP doesn't allow bidirectional stateful connections. You don't have that limitation when you're developing a native app (except if you're using Apache Cordova or similar, but then you'd be using Javascript). So why are you taking this route?

Comment: Hi Carsten. I don't know of any other duplex protocol that allows real-time data push from server to client. Push notification services for native apps (like GCM) are not real-time. Do you know any alternative way?

Comment: 0MQ is a solution for streaming pub/sub. http://zeromq.org/

Comment: @ticofab: Take a look at XMPP also.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two parts in a WebSocket connection: the server and the client. You could just make the server part using Play2 and implement a client with Android (see [websocket-android-phonegap](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap)), iOS (see [Unitt](https://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient)), javascript app...

Here is an example for a *very* basic websocket connection taken from http://blog.tksfz.org/2012/10/12/websockets-echo-using-play-scala-and-actors-part-i/:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {
  def index = WebSocket.using[String] {
    val out = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String] {
      msg =>
        out.push(msg)
    }
    (in, out)
  }
}
```

You only have to set a route that points to your controller `conf/routes`:

```
GET /connect  Application.index
```

The server is ready to run. You can then connect to your WebSocket with a javascript application, an Android application, etc... The client side is another matter.

If you use chrome or chromium, just open your javascript console in developer tools and you can connect to your server just like that:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/connect')
ws.onmessage = function( message ) { console.log( message ); };
ws.send('test')
```

It will send you back your message and log it in the javascript console whenever you send one.

You could also just use the http://www.websocket.org/echo.html echo test and feed it your `'ws://localhost:9000/connect'` url.

Comment: `Enumerator.imperative` appears to be deprecated or removed from recent versions of Play, this is an echo app in a newer version: http://blog.controlgroup.com/2013/10/17/simple-websockets-example-play-2-2-0/ hope this helps someone else...

Comment: That link is dead, try this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-iteratees

Answer (score 2):

Either you could use a pain old Socket, but you'll have problems with port forwarding (ie through firewalls) or you can could use Websocket client library, such as this one in Java :http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html